# TERADATA - Return a simple query in my stored procedure

Tags: teradata

I am very new to stored procedures and SQL programming and I am doing some experiments.

My first experiment is to simply execute a `SELECT` statement by using a stored procedure.

This is my procedure:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_QUERY_EXECUTION()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE SQL_SELECT VARCHAR(100);
            SET SQL_SELECT = 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;';
        EXECUTE SQL_SELECT;
    END;
```

I was expecting to see the contend of the table MY_TABLE, but I get an error

> SPL5004:E(L18), Referring to undefined statement 'SQL_SELECT'

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Been a while, but try `CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQ(SQL_SELECT)`

Comment: You need DYNAMIC RESULT SETS clause and a CURSOR WITH RETURN. See the manual [here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/SQL-Stored-Procedures-and-Embedded-SQL/SQL-Stored-Procedures/Returning-Result-Sets-from-a-Stored-Procedure)